# Powerquery categorise column by matching text values against a list

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

```
NextStep = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Clear nulls (approx 3)", 
    "Has process source", 
    each 
        [Source for process flows] <> "Source - No" and 
        [Source for process flows] <> "Source not found" and 
        Text.Lower([Source for process flows]) <> "source not available" and 
        [Source for process flows] <> null and 
        [Source for process flows] <> "?", 
    type logical
)
```

Is there a less dumb way to do this?

I want to convert a text column containing status updates into a True/False column.

Comment: At least there is a "less dumb" way to format the code. Besides that you could try **List.Contains()** but I'm not sure if it's really an improvement.

Comment: Can you share your sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could name the column to something shorter:

```
NextStep = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Clear nulls (approx 3)", 
    "Has process source", each
    let
        s = [Source for process flows],
        res = s <> "Source - No" and 
              s <> "Source not found" and 
              Text.Lower(s) <> "source not available" and 
              s <> null and 
              s <> "?"
    in
        res, type logical
)
```

and maybe use an exclusion list like @Peter suggested:

```
excList = {"Source - No","Source not found",null,"?"},
NextStep = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Clear nulls (approx 3)", 
    "Has process source", each
    let
        s = [Source for process flows],
        res = (not List.Contains(excList,s)) and
              Text.Lower(s) <> "source not available"
    in
        res, type logical
)
```

Comment: Thanks, did not expect you to answer! Both good suggestions, latter was what I was really getting at (my exclusion list is ever growing)

Comment: @Greedo Thanks! May I ask why you did not expect me to answer? I use PQ quite a lot - when speed is not an issue :)

Comment: Ah just a different circle to the VBA content was all. But yes it's another useful tool integrated into Excel so makes sense you would be familiar.